# Accessing the member function of an object which is an element of the vector of class

Tags: c++

With reference to the code(just an example) below is it possible to access the member function(say setCdata()) of an object using the
iterator i or do i have to use another variable to keep a count of the index of element?

```
   class Cdata
    {
    public : 
    int a = 0;

    //constructor
    //destructor

    setCdata();
    }

    void main()
    {
       vector<CData> dat;
       dat.push_back(1);
       dat.push_back(2);
       dat.push_back(3);

        //Define an iterator
        vector<CData>::iterator i;
        for(i = cl.begin(); i != cl.end(); i++)
        {
            dat[count].setCdata(); //is there a way of accessing the print() by using just the iterator i??     
            count++;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can simply use one of the following:

```
i->setCdata();
(*i).setCdata();
```

Notice that in C++11 you can also use the following notation:

```
for(auto& e : cl)
    e.setCdata();
```